# Biblatex and per-year subbibliography

Tags: biblatex, sorting

My question is how I can group the bibliographic records using biblatex on per-year-basis. I have tried the approach

```
\newcounter{mycounter}
\setcounter{mycounter}{2013}
\defbibcheck{intheyear}{
  \iffieldint{year}
  {\ifnum \thefield{year} = \themycounter
    {\skipentry}
    {} }
  {\skipentry}}
```

and then using the command

```
\printbibliography[title=2013
,heading=subbibliography
,type=article
,check = intheyear
]
```

changing the counter value manually, but this yields a result only if the command is called once. In the second calling of `\printbibliography`, `pdflatex` announces

> ```
> ! Incomplete \ifnum; all text was ignored after line <i>xx</i>.
> <inserted text> 
>                 \fi 
> <*> \input lpublications.tex
>
> ! Emergency stop.
> <*> \input lpublications.tex
> ```

What I want to achieve is that I will have structure of references as

> 2013
>
> Braham, A., Edrich, B. ...
>
> Ecilie, C., Ietrich, D. ...
>
> 2012
>
> .....

If this was done automatically according to entries in `.bib` file. It would be fine. I have really no idea how to do that.

Comment: You might be able to use `biblatex`'s concept of categories together with the `\bibbycategory`.

Comment: `\ifnum` requires `\fi`. You may use for example
`\ifnumequal{\thefield{year}}{\themycounter}`

Answer (score 6):

In the code below the first `\printbibliography` composes a list of years which is then used in a loop to print other bibliographies. The `sorting` option is used to sort the list (thanks to user32884 for suggesting this).

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{a1,
 author = {Author},
 title = {Title},
 journaltitle = {Superjournal},
 year = {2003},
}
@ARTICLE{a2,
 author = {Buthor},
 title = {Ztitle},
 journaltitle = {Superjournal},
 year = {2000},
}
@ARTICLE{a3,
 author = {Duthor},
 title = {Ztitle},
 journaltitle = {Superjournal},
 year = {2002},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\newcounter{mycounter}
\defbibcheck{intheyear}{
  \iffieldint{year}
    {\ifnumequal{\thefield{year}}{\themycounter}
      {}
      {\skipentry}}
    {\skipentry}}
\defbibenvironment{counting}
  {}
  {}
  {\xifinlist{\thefield{year}}{\yearlist}
    {}
    {\listxadd{\yearlist}{\thefield{year}}}}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\gdef\yearlist{}%
\begingroup%
  \makeatletter%
  \def\blx@driver#1{}%
  \printbibliography[env=counting,heading=none,type=article,sorting=ydnt]%
  \makeatother%
\endgroup%
\renewcommand*{\do}[1]{%
  \setcounter{mycounter}{#1}%
  \printbibliography[title=#1
  ,heading=subbibliography
  ,type=article
  ,check = intheyear
  ]}
\dolistloop{\yearlist}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thnak you, this helped. I just had to remove double braces {{ }} at my year fields of the bib file to work. I also could solve the sorting problem by declaring my sorting scheme by `\DeclareSortingScheme{dyear}{

  \sort[direction=descending]{\field{year}}

  \sort{\field{author}}

  \sort{

    \field{journal}

    \field{title}

  }
}
` 
and modifying the group `\begingroup%
  \makeatletter%
  \def\blx@driver#1{}%
  \printbibliography[env=counting,heading=none,type=article,sorting=dyear]%
  \makeatother%
\endgroup%
`

Comment: Oh, yes, a simple solution, it didn't come to my mind. There is actually a standard sorting scheme `ydnt` which can be used for that. I added it to the answer. I also removed `\AtEveryBibitem` while modifying a little the `counting` environment.

Comment: This works great for me, except the years of my publications are now sorted in ascending instead of descending order. I copied and pasted the code without modification. Not sure what went wrong.